# Joi Promises with ES returning err

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, joi

```
              registerController.validate(request.payload).then((err) => {
                if(err === null) {
                    reply(true);
                }
            }); 
          validate: function (data) {
            return new Promise ((resolve) => {
                Joi.validate({
                    username: data.username,
                    password: data.password,
                    email: data.email
                }, RegisterSchema,function () {
                    resolve(err);
                });

});
```

}

Im sure err is null :D What am i doing wrong? i was trying with this and bluebird but nothing was working :/

Comment: You haven't declared `err` anywhere, so it's `undefined` (and throws in strict mode). Presumably you meant to use a parameter in the callback?

Comment: You shouldn't `resolve` your promise with an error, you should `reject` it when there is one (and fulfill it otherwise).

Comment: I need to check the err (err from joi.validate)  is null or not.. :/  then i will check is validating finished without any errors or with errors (when i declare err in "RegisterSchema, function (err)" nothing happen

Comment: What do you mean by "*err from joi.validate*"? And where is that check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declared `err` anywhere, so it's `undefined` (and throws in strict mode). Presumably you meant to use a parameter in the callback?

Also you shouldn't `resolve` your promise with an error, you should `reject` it when there is one (and fulfill it otherwise). So use

```
validate: function (data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Joi.validate(data, RegisterSchema, function(err) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(true); // or a result if there is one?
        });
    });
}
```

```
registerController.validate(request.payload).then(reply, err => {
    replyError(…) // or something
});
```